# Unable to start service wampmysqld

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

my wamp server was working completely fine till today morning. But an hour ago when I tried to start my server, I got the below error.

[image]

I restarted my MySQL notifier plus restarted my MySQL server.
Second thing is, there's absolutely nothing in my logs.
Here;s the last logs that I have in file.

```
014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Binlog end
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-11-07 01:40:11 5332 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 9080881
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-11-07 01:40:14 5332 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-11-07 01:40:15 5332 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Have you rebooted your server/pc?

Comment: I might loose all the my database and settings.

Comment: Backup, take dumps of your database and insert them in your new install: http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2013/07/19/12-steps-to-rebuild-your-wamp-server-without-losing-your-data/

Comment: What have you installed recently, since you last ran WAMPServer?

Comment: Earlier, once i got this issue. I searched and found a solution which looks completely stupid on first hand, but it worked. The trick was to either uninstall or quit skype. The explanation was something like, both application are accessing same ports.

Comment: Hay @JackSparrow it's true Skype and WampServer uses the same post 80 you can do the following 

In skype:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative". This should help.

Answer (score 0):

Its always skype --> tools ---> connection options , change connection port to 8080 or something like that to avoid further problems